# Custom Taxonomy user based creation

Tags: custom-taxonomy, users

I need to create a **User based Custom Post Custom Taxonomy Term**, so in admin and frontend I can relate the Creation/Update & Delete of the term to the current logged in user.

Is there a relationship table to do this, or do I have to create one myself (meta)? If already implemented in WP, how can I create/get/update/delete data for this?

Answer (score 0):

Re,

I think i figure out this topic.

To create a user based Term in Custom Taxonomy, i've created a meta attached to the term (new WP 4.4 feature) 'author' which contains the logged in user ID :

```
add_term_meta($term_id,'author',get_current_user_id());
```

and then to retrieve the user who has created the term :

```
$author = get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename', intval(get_term_meta($term_id,'author')) );
```

I think it's the best way to do it.

cheers !

Comment: You should [accept](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) your own answer (*and all answers to other questions which helped you*) ;-)